# Can diffraction be used like gravitational lensing

Tags: diffraction, gravitational-lensing

I was thinking that in both the cases of diffraction and gravitational lensing, light is bend to some extent mimicking the lens effect. My Question is, Can diffraction be used like gravitational lensing in the sense that gravitational lensing is usable for objects which are very very far(in light-years or parsecs), similarly can diffraction be used for short ranges(In meters) like a glass lens

Comment: Diffraction is a phenomenon that typically happens around objects that are of comparable length to the wavelength of the diffracted waves (although one can do it with much larger objects, if certain coherence conditions are fulfilled). Gravitational lensing happens on a scale much, much, much larger than that, so I would say, not, it's not a very good comparison.

Comment: "used like..." to do what?

Comment: Tom's answer explains nicely how diffraction can be used to create a lensing effect. Note however that image formation by diffraction is entirely different from gravitational lensing. Not only are the mechanisms unrelated, but even the end results are different as gravitational lenses have a focal line not a focal point.

Comment: @JohnRennie, I know they are different, but my question is can diffraction create a lens effect and is it similar to gravitational lensing

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, It's "used like a glass lens". Hope that clarifies it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take you question to be 'can diffraction act as a lens in the same way that a gravitational field can act as a lens' then the answer is yes. Yes with [Zone Plates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_plate).

Zone plates look like diffraction patterns. for example see the image below
[image]

When light passes through the zone plate it will be focussed in a way that is very similar to the way a lens focusses light. I have seen zone plates used with a coherent source of x-rays because there is not really any material that could be used as a traditional glass lens to make an image with x-rays.

It is not straight forward to explain how a zone plate works. The way I think about it is the following. If you imagine monochromatic light from a point source hitting a screen after passing through a single circular apperture you get a pattern like the zone plate. Now if we imagine that we reverse the path of the light and have monochromatic coherent light coming through a zone plate with the same pattern then it should be focussed to a point the same distance from the zone plate as the circular apperture was from the diffraction pattern.